# MVC 301 redirect from www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/en

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have an mvc3 website in 3 languages.

English is the default language, so if you visit `mysite.com` or `mysite.com/en` you get the same page.

What I want is a 301 redirect from `mysite.com` (or `mysite.com/`) to

```
mysite.com/en
```

Which is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

PS

I managed the site localization following [this](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html) article.

Comment: Aside: do you really need the /en route? What value does it add? Why not just have mysite.com + mysite.com/[other languages than English]?

Comment: Yes it would better I think, but I don't know how to manage the missing culture. Do you have some examples? By the way I wonder how to manage the 301 redirect too. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have each culture set up as its own area?

Comment: If you mean MVC Areas, nope. Culture is one route param, I have a custom MvcRouteHandler reading the culture from RouteData and setting the CurrentThread culture. Then I sue resx files for localized resources.

Comment: Best is kinda subjective. Would you rather do it in code or configure IIS to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I would setup [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to check the incoming url. If the url doesn't have two characters at the start then you can assume that it needs to be rewritten, and you should do a redirect to the url with en appended to the start.

This does assume that you don't have any genuine routes with 2 characters at the beginning... if that isn't the case then you could check for a set of different 2 characters language values.

Comment: Why? Using IIS URL Rewrite is a cleanest solution IMHO.

Comment: I would argue that [using a "RedirectRoute"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535976/mvc-301-redirect-from-www-mysite-com-to-www-mysite-com-en/6546830#6546830) is cleaner - that way you have both the routes and the redirect(s) defined in the same place.

Comment: Thanks Anders, can you send an example?

Comment: @opaera I [already did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535976/mvc-301-redirect-from-www-mysite-com-to-www-mysite-com-en/6546830#6546830).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("http://mysite.com/en/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I check if the culture is present? When you access mysite.com, in the Index(), RouteData contains the default culture value, so I don't know if the Url has it or not. I should work on the Url string, but I don't think this is good..

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow you. From your question I interpreted that you have already implemented localization, and that you only wanted to set a default culture when people hit your HomeController.Index(), redirecting from / to /en/. In this case you don't need to know if the culture is present, because you are setting it. If this is not the case, what do you need to do with the current culture?

Answer (score 0):

I would have two routes and two actions, one to do the redirection depending on the culture [eg. Index() ], and the other one that takes the language as a parameter [Index(string language)]

Answer (score 0):

In Phil Haack's [RouteMagic](http://routemagic.codeplex.com/) helper library (which he [blogged about](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx) a while ago), there is a [RedirectRoute extension](http://routemagic.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b177f9ddcfff#src/RouteMagic/RedirectRouteExtensions.cs) that provides a clean way to define routes that redirect to other routes using permanent redirects. I think that would be a more "discoverable" solution than using IIS settings. It's [available via NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/RouteMagic).

Phil has also [written a post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx) that pretty much exactly describes what you are trying to do, using RouteMagic.